# How to compound terms query and bool query together in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

Originally, I would add a `filter` in the bool query. However, when I turn to `terms filter`, the [documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/query-dsl-terms-filter.html) indicates that it should be replaced by `terms query` now. So I understand this as that we need to construct a compound query with both `terms query` and `bool query`. If I am correct, how should I write the query?

Note: I use elasticsearch's Python API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two types of context now: [query context and filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/query-filter-context.html). Any query clause inside query context contribute to the score of matching document i.e. how well a document matched a query whereas any query clause inside filter context determines whether or not the document matches and doesn't contribute to the score.

So in the query below I have marked both the contexts:

```
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [
        { "match": { "field1":   "terms1"}},              <------query context
      ],
      "filter": [ 
        { "terms":  { "someId": [3242, 12343, 1234] }},   <-------inside filter block every query clause will act as filter (filter context)
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Therefore in order to use terms query as a filter you need to follow the below steps:

1. Create a bool query say `boolQuery`
2. Create a terms query sat `termsQuery`
3. Add `termsQuery` to filter of `boolQuery`.
4. Set `boolQuery` as query.

This translates to below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "field1": ["terms1", "term2", "terms3"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: sounds like I totally misunderstand the document.

Comment: No worries. People are here to clear doubts and help.